# Java MaxFlow Algorithm, Trouble Generating Edges

Tags: java, graph, max-flow

I'm trying to solve the max flow problem with the graph having unlimited weight edges but each node has a capacity. I solved the problem using ford fulkerson algorithm and splitting each node into an in node and an out node with the capacity being the weighted edge between the two. My algorithm works great when i hard code in the edges (see commented out block in code), but always returns zero when I try to build edges from a text file. For the life of me I can not figure out why, I have checked to make sure all the edges are being constructed properly, and just cant figure out whats wrong.

Text file for reading graph (1st line is edges, 2nd is capacity of nodes)
(1 2) (2 3) (2 5) (3 4) (4 5) (3 5)
(2 1500) (3 1000) (4 800)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {


//Add Node to Graph
public static void make_node(Map<String, List<Edge>> graph, String node_v) {
    List<Edge> empty = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!graph.containsKey(node_v)) {
        graph.put(node_v, empty);
    }
}

//Create Edge
public static void make_edge(Map<String, List<Edge>> graph, Map<Edge, Integer> flow_graph, String node_u, String node_v, int weight) {
    Edge edge = new Edge(node_u, node_v, weight);
    Edge residual_flow = new Edge(node_v, node_u, 0);

    edge.setRisedge(residual_flow);
    residual_flow.setRisedge(edge);

    if (graph.containsKey(node_u)) {
        List<Edge> edge_list = graph.get(node_u);
        edge_list.add(edge);
        graph.put(node_u, edge_list);
    }
    if (graph.containsKey(node_v)) {
        List<Edge> edge_list = graph.get(node_v);
        edge_list.add(residual_flow);
        graph.put(node_v, edge_list);
    }

    flow_graph.put(edge, 0);
    flow_graph.put(residual_flow, 0);

}

//Find valid path to Sink
public static List<Edge> get_path(Map<String, List<Edge>> graph, Map<Edge, Integer> flow_graph, String source, String sink, List<Edge> path) {
    if (source == sink)
        return path;

    int residual;
    List<Edge> result;

    for (Edge edge : graph.get(source)) {
        residual = edge.getCapacity() - flow_graph.get(edge);
        if (residual > 0 && !path.contains(edge) && !path.contains(edge.getRisedge())) {
            path.add(edge);
            result = get_path(graph, flow_graph, edge.getSink(), sink, path);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}

//Find Max Flow
public static int find_max_flow(Map<String, List<Edge>> graph, Map<Edge, Integer> flow_graph, String source, String sink) {
    List<Edge> path = new ArrayList<>();
    path = get_path(graph, flow_graph, source, sink, path);
    List<Integer> residuals = new ArrayList<>();
    int min_path_flow;

    while (path != null) {
        for (Edge edge : path) {
            residuals.add(edge.getCapacity() - flow_graph.get(edge));
        }
        min_path_flow = Collections.min(residuals);

        for (Edge edge : path) {
            flow_graph.put(edge, flow_graph.get(edge) + min_path_flow);
            flow_graph.put(edge.getRisedge(), flow_graph.get(edge.getRisedge()) - min_path_flow);
        }
        List<Edge> empty = new ArrayList<>();
        path = get_path(graph, flow_graph, source, sink, empty);
    }

    int max_flow = 0;
    for (Edge edge : graph.get(source)) {
        max_flow += flow_graph.get(edge);
    }
    return max_flow;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Map<String, List<Edge>> graph = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Edge, Integer> flow_graph = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> capacity_dict = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> in_out_nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    //Get file name
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name:");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String graph_text = reader.readLine();
    String capacity_text = reader.readLine();

    //Parse Capacity
    capacity_text = capacity_text.replace(")", "");
    capacity_text = capacity_text.replace("(", "");
    String[] split_capacity = capacity_text.split("\\s");

    //Parse Graph
    graph_text = graph_text.replace(")", "");
    graph_text = graph_text.replace("(", "");
    String[] split_graph = graph_text.split("\\s");

    //Parse Capacity
    for (int i = 0; i < split_capacity.length; i++){
        if(!capacity_dict.containsKey(split_capacity[i])){
            capacity_dict.put(split_capacity[i],Integer.valueOf(split_capacity[i+1]));
            in_out_nodes.add(split_capacity[i]);
            i = i+1;
        }
    }

    //Make nodes
    for (String s : split_graph){
        make_node(graph, s + "out");
        make_node(graph, s + "in");
    }

    //Make edges
    for (int i = 0; i < split_graph.length; i ++){
        String u = split_graph[i] + "out";
        String ui = split_graph[i] + "in";
        String v = split_graph[i + 1] + "in";

        if(in_out_nodes.contains(split_graph[i])){
            in_out_nodes.remove(split_graph[i]);
            make_edge(graph,flow_graph,u,ui, capacity_dict.get(split_graph[i]) );
        }

        if(capacity_dict.containsKey(split_graph[i])){
            make_edge(graph,flow_graph,u,v, capacity_dict.get(split_graph[i]) );

        }else{
            make_edge(graph,flow_graph,u,v, capacity_dict.get(split_graph[i + 1]) );

        }
        i += 1;
    }

    //Code works when i comment out my generated edges and use these
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "1out","2in",1500);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "2out","3in",1500);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "2out","5in",1500);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "3out","4in",1000);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "4out","5in",800);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "3out","5in",1000);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "2in","2out",1500);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "3in","3out",1000);
    //make_edge(graph,flow_graph, "4in","4out",800);

    System.out.print(find_max_flow(graph, flow_graph, "1out", "5in"));
}
}
```

Edge Class

```
public class Edge {

public Edge(String source, String sink, int capacity) {
    this.source = source;
    this.sink = sink;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

private String source;
private String sink;
private int capacity;
private Edge risedge;

public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public String getSink() {
    return sink;
}

public void setSink(String sink) {
    this.sink = sink;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public Edge getRisedge() {
    return risedge;
}

public void setRisedge(Edge risedge) {
    this.risedge = risedge;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest, your code is a mess. I cannot tell what is your point of failure. Since your program works for hard-coding edges, something is wrong with your graph. And indeed, I created some outputs to compare both graphs.

Your hard coded graphs looks like the following. The edge is represented by

`name_of_source -> name_of_sink (capacity)`

```
1in: []
2in: [2in -> 1out (0), 2in -> 2out (0)]
3in: [3in -> 2out (0), 3in -> 3out (0)]
4in: [4in -> 3out (0), 4in -> 4out (0)]
5in: [5in -> 2out (0), 5in -> 4out (0), 5in -> 3out (0)]
1out: [1out -> 2in (1500)]
2out: [2out -> 2in (1500), 2out -> 3in (1500), 2out -> 5in (1500)]
3out: [3out -> 3in (1000), 3out -> 4in (1000), 3out -> 5in (1000)]
4out: [4out -> 4in (800), 4out -> 5in (800)]
5out: []
```

But when you build the same graph without hard coding you get:

```
1in: []
2in: [2in -> 1out (0), 2in -> 2out (1500)]
3in: [3in -> 2out (0), 3in -> 3out (1000)]
4in: [4in -> 3out (0), 4in -> 4out (800)]
5in: [5in -> 2out (0), 5in -> 4out (0), 5in -> 3out (0)]
1out: [1out -> 2in (1500)]
2out: [2out -> 3in (1500), 2out -> 5in (1500), 2out -> 2in (0)]
3out: [3out -> 4in (1000), 3out -> 5in (1000), 3out -> 3in (0)]
4out: [4out -> 5in (800), 4out -> 4in (0)]
5out: []
```

To define a string representation of any class, you have to override the toString() method from Object. I added the following method to your Edge class to produce this output.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return source + " -> " + sink + " (" + capacity + ")";
}
```

And the following code produces the output of your graph variable:

```
for ( String k : graph.keySet() )
    System.out.println( k + ": " + graph.get(k));
```

I'm pretty sure that's enough help for you to solve the problem.